# extract position of char from each row & provide an aggregate of position across a list

Tags: python-3.x, extract

I need some python help with this problem. Would appreciate any assistance !. Thanks.

I need an extracted matrix of values enclosed between square brackets. A toy example is below:

File Input will be in a txt file as below:

AB_1    Q[A]IHY[P]GVA

AB_2    Q[G][C]HY[R]GVA

AB_3    Q[G][C]HY[R]GV[D]

Answer out.txt: Script extracts index of char enclosed between sq.brackets "[]" for each row from input and makes an aggregate of index positions for the entire list. The aggregated index is then used to extract all of those positions from input file and produce a matrix as below.

Index   2,3,6,9

AB_1    [A],I,[P],A

AB_2    [G],[C],[R],A

AB_3    [G],[C],[R],[D]

Any help would be greatly appreciated !. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce your table to only those columns in which an entry with square-brackets appears, you can go with this:

```
import re

def transpose(matrix):
    return [[matrix[j][i] for j in range(len(matrix))] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]

with open("test_table.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

rows = [re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', line.split()[1]) for line in content.split("\n")]

columns = transpose(rows)
matching_columns = [[str(i + 1)] + column for i, column in enumerate(columns) if "[" in "".join(column)]

matching_rows = transpose(matching_columns)

headline = ["Index {}".format(",".join(matching_rows[0]))]
target_table = headline + ["AB_{0} {1}".format((i + 1), ",".join(line)) for i, line in enumerate(matching_rows[1:])]

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(target_table))
```

First of all you want the content of your .txt file to be represented in arrays. Unfortunately your input data has no seperators yet (as in .csv files) so you need to take care of that. To get a string like this `"Q[A]IHY[P]GVA"` sorted out I would recommend working with regular expressions.

```
import re
cells = re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', "Q[A]IHY[P]GVA")
```

The pattern within the `r''` string matches *a single character within square brackets* **or** *just a single character*. The `re.findall()` method returns a list of all matching substrings, in this case: `['Q', '[A]', 'I', 'H', 'Y', '[P]', 'G', 'V', 'A']`

`rows = [re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', line.split()[1]) for line in content.split("\n")]` applies this method on every line in your file. The `line.split()[1]` will leave out the row label "AB_X " as it is not usefull.

Having your data sorted in `columns` is more fitting, because you want to preserve all columns that match a certain condition (contain an entry in brackets). For this you can just transpose `rows`. This is done by the `transpose()` function. If you have imported numpy `numpy.transpose(rows)` would be the better option I guess.

Next you want to get all columns that satisfy your condition `"[" in "".join(column)`. All done in one line by: `matching_columns = [[str(i + 1)] + column for i, column in enumerate(columns) if "[" in "".join(column)]` Here `[str(i + 1)]` does add the column index that you want to use later.

The rest now is easy: Transpose the columns back to rows, relabel the rows, format the row data into strings that fit your desired output format and then write those strings to the `out.txt` file.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for taking on this. I get the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_freq.py", line 9, in <module>
    rows = [re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', line.split()[1]) for line in content.split("\n")]
  File "script_freq.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    rows = [re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', line.split()[1]) for line in content.split("\n")]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yes, this is probably due to `line.split()[1]` which takes a string, e.g. `"Hello World"` and splits it on white spaces: `["Hello", "World"]`. Taking the index `[1]` would return `"World"`. If there is no white spice, e.g. `"Hello"` it returns `["Hello"]` if you try to access the 1th element of this you'll run into an index error.
On the data sample you provided, I assumed it has no blank lines. To handle blank lines you could go with: `rows = [re.findall(r'(\[.\]|.)', line.split()[1]) for line in content.split("\n") if "AB_" in line]`